# Regex find hash comments exclude curly brackets

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I want to find the hash comments that don't contain the text inside curly braces. **But if it starts with #, it's all comments.**

Input：

```
# This is comment 1
TEST # This is comment 2
{  # Not comment}; { # Not comment } # This is example 3

# This is comment 4
TEST Not comment
{  # Not comment}; { # Not comment } # This is comment 5

{# Not comment}; { # Not comment }={# Not comment} {# Not comment}={# Not comment} {# Not comment}={# Not comment} # This is comment 6
# This is comment 7 {# This is comment 8}

# This is comment 9

Not comment {Not comment}={# Not comment}
```

Output:

```
# This is comment 1
# This is comment 2
# This is comment 3
# This is comment 4
# This is comment 5
# This is comment 6
# This is comment 7 {# This is comment 8}
# This is comment 9
```

I want to be able to achieve what I want with one line of regular expression.
Currently I can only find all strings starting with # by `\{.*?}(*SKIP)(*F)|#[^#{}\n].*`
However it doesn't work in python(I hope not PCRE).

If possible I hope it can be done without installing the module 'regex' to parsing PCRE(Perl Compatible Regular Expressions).

Comment: This is too difficult to obtain with plain regex. Depending on the input (and regex flavor), you might try workarounds. Eg. `(?m)#[^#\n]*\r?$`, `/#[^#\r\n]*$/gm`, etc. ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/cbzAUy/1)).

Comment: Maybe something like `\{.*?}(*SKIP)(*F)|#[^#{}\n]+`. But that's a shot in the dark since I don't know where a comment would end/if there can be successive comments.

Comment: Sorry I didn't describe my problem clearly ~ re-update my input.

Comment: @JvdV I evolved from your answer to find my answer, but it doesn't work in python. **\{.*?}(*SKIP)(*F)|^\#.*|#[^#{}\n]+**

Comment: @samlin, you could use pypi regex module. Import regex as re

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix begin and end of line separators at the boundaries of your regex, and then look for:

- all strings that start with a `#` and that don't include new lines: `"(#[^\n]+)"`

optionally precedeed by:

- any character (other than a new line) followed by a space `"(.+ )?"`

Here's the final regex:

```
"(^|\n)(.+ )?(#[^\n]+)"
```

Tested at https://regex101.com. Use backreference to retrieve your comment within Group 3.

Does it work for you?

Comment: Thanks for your help but can't seem to find all the comments. I have updated my input text and you can try it again.

Comment: Updated my answer, for further corner cases, please provide more in the question or here in the comments, thanks! @SamLin

Comment: I think this has met my needs, thanks a lot.